# Xamarin .NET 4.5 missing (windows 8)

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I am getting this warning from Xamarin while building a console app.

The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed.

I tried installing .NET 4.5 but the installs tells me that I already have .NET 4.5 installed with my OS (Windows 8), but if it does, why is Xamarin returning this error?

I also tried searching how to retarget Xamarin but I cant find anything that helps.

Comment: Just like JRE and JDK, .NET Framework and .NET Framework SDK are different.

Answer (score 1):

This warning is from MSBuild it is not coming from Xamarin. The reference assemblies are not installed if you only install the .NET Framework runtime. They are part of the SDK. So if you install the .NET Framework 4.5 SDK then the warning should no longer be displayed.

A search for .NET 4.5 Framework SDK returns the following page which has links for all the runtimes and SDKs for each .NET Framework version:

http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html